# Best Practice - CRUD operations MVC4

Tags: crud

I want to know if there is better way to implement CRUD mentioned below.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult EditStudent(int studentID)
    {
        Student obj = StudentBAL.GetStudent(id);
        return View(obj);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult EditStudent([Bind(Include="LastName,FirstMidName,EnrollmentDate")]Student model)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

I don't want to pass StudentID(primary key) to client end as it can be modified easily from developer tools(Firebug etc.). I have excluded studentid on POST request too. Let me know how i can perform update/change without passing primarykey.

Comment: Create a custom model binder which will encrypt the primary key before sending it to the client and decrypt it when receiving data back.

Comment: however, it can be tampered though. Any other alternative..?